# Java calling PL/SQL Stored Procedure with Table as IN Paramater

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I've been trying to find a way for java to send a table datatype to a stored procedure but can't get around on how java can pass a table to stored procedure.

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE SPNAME(
INPUT_PARAMS IN USER.TABLENAME
)
AS
INSERTVALUES VARCHAR2(10000);
BEGIN
-- do stuffs     
END SPNAME;
```

Comment: Example here https://technology.amis.nl/2008/07/16/oracle-jdbc-passing-a-table-of-custom-object-type-to-a-stored-procedure-implementing-efficient-single-round-trip-data-exchange-part-two-of-an-adf-application-on-a-plsql-api/

Comment: @Mike That link is specific to using Oracle ADF.  It's not applicable to java and jdbc in general.

Comment: Can you post your java code that you've tried?

Comment: @mark Stewart, I've really no idea how it works.

Comment: Well if you post it, someone might have an idea how it works and why you are having trouble.